# Formula manipulation ( split random effects)

Tags: r

I am trying to build up a mixed effects model validation tool for which I am using forward selection approach, so if suppose the model is `model<-y~a+b+(1+c|d)`, (both random intercept and random slope included), I can use findbars function under lme4 package in R `findbars(model)` to separate the random effects, i.e. `(1+c|d)` in this example, but since I am using a forward selection approach, I want first the random intercept only model i.e. `(1|d)`, and then the full random effects model `(1+c|d)`. Is there any way to split the random effects `(1|d)` if I see `(1+c|d)` in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a lot more complicated than I'd like, but I think this is what's necessary:

```
##' combine unary or binary operator + arguments (sugar for 'substitute')
makeOp <- function(x,y,op=NULL) {
   if (is.null(op)) {  ## unary
    substitute(OP(X),list(X=x,OP=y))
   } else substitute(OP(X,Y), list(X=x,OP=op,Y=y))
}
## convert character to raw 'language' object
toLang <- function(x) parse(text=x)[[1]]
## expand term using terms()
splitFun <- function(x) {
    tt <- terms(as.formula(makeOp(x,quote(`~`))))
    res <- lapply(attr(tt,"term.labels"),toLang)
    if (attr(tt,"intercept")==1) {
        res <- c(list(1),res)
    }
    return(res)
}
## expand left-hand side terms into a list, 
##   distribute across right-hand sides
expandFun <- function(x) {
    lapply(splitFun(x[[2]]),makeOp,y=x[[3]],op=quote(`|`))
}
```

Try it out:

```
form <- y~a+b+(1+c|d)
bb <- lme4::findbars(form)
lapply(bb,expandFun)
## [[1]]
## [[1]][[1]]
## 1 | d
## 
## [[1]][[2]]
## c | d
```

This code will also expand, e.g. `x*y` into `1+x+y+x:y` (not sure if you want that to happen or not ...)

PS: you do know about the inferential dangers of stepwise model selection, right?  (e.g. see [here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/))